# Django and Postgres inserting into many-to-many table not working

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm using python and psycopg2 to scrape some data and insert them into my database.

I've already created the ***movies*** and ***actors*** tables inside my Django models.py and inside my movies table, there is a many to many relationship between movies and actors table.

below is my models.py:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=1024)
    actor = models.ManyToManyField(Actor, blank=True)
```

when I create a movie from Django-admin I select which actors are included in the movie and everything works fine and all the related actors for that movie will show up on my website.

But the problem is that when I try to insert scraped data into my database outside of my Django project folder, the related actors **won't be shown** on my website because obviously, I have not set the many to many relationship between them.

I have tried creating a **junction table** using SQL commands which gets the movie id and the actor's id and links them together but I don't know how I should tell Django to use that table and show the related actors for each movie.

This is the SQL code I use to insert into my db:

```
INSERT INTO movies(name, summary)
VALUES ('movie name', 'sth')
```

and the code to insert to actors table:

```
INSERT INTO actors(name, bio)
VALUES ('actorname', 'sth')
```

Both actors and movies table have auto generated id and I insert them insto the junction table using the code below:

```
INSERT INTO movie_actors (actor_id, movie_id) 
VALUES (
(SELECT actor_id from actors where name='actor name'),
(SELECT movie_id from movie where name='movie name')
)
```

Am I doing it right?

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this.

Comment: Hi, please add a minimal reproducible example.More info: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi, I just updated my question @EPaul

Answer (score 0):

Django automatically creates a table for many2many relationships. From docs:

ManyToManyField.through
Django will automatically generate a table to manage many-to-many relationships. However, if you want to manually specify the intermediary table, you can use the through option to specify the Django model that represents the intermediate table that you want to use.

The most common use for this option is when you want to associate extra data with a many-to-many relationship.

So you must find the name of the table that django had already created.
Secondly, I suggest that you use django's ORM instead of raw queries so you don't have these kind of problems anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so where should I look for this table? @EPaul

Answer (score 0):

Django automatically creates a through table  for M2M relations, if you need you can specify custom through table. In your case I think there is no need of custom through table.

I using Django ORM instead of writing raw query.

`INSERT INTO movies(name, summary) VALUES ('movie name', 'sth')`

instead of tis raw query you can use the following ORM query:

`movie = Movie.objects.create(name="movie name", summary="movie sammuary")`

This will create a movie entry in the Movie table.

Next to create user entry you can use the following query:

`actor = Actor.objects.create(name="actor name", bio="actor bio")`

Now you created the entries in both the table, next you can establish the realtion, for that you have to use the following query:

`movie.actor.add(actor)`

Incase if you want to add multiple actors at the same time, you create multiple actors object and use following query:

`movie.actor.add(actor1, actor2, actor2)`

For more details you can check [django's offical documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)